# Play Framework MySQL connection using password different from default

Tags: mysql, playframework, config, playframework-2.3

I don't have problems for connection with MySQL if I'm using this configuration in Play Framework application.conf:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass=root
```

However when I use a user and password different from `root root` (I previously created in phpmyadmin from MAMP a user with name `play` and I checked `Create database with same name and grant all privileges` box), it returns me a "connection error".

I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=play
db.default.pass=play
```

I tried also replacing the last line with this, but nothing:
`db.default.pass="play"`

Where was I wrong?

Comment: Maybe try with `db.default.password=secret` instead of `db.default.pass=secret`?

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work: I tested both `db.default.password=secret` and `db.default.password="secret"` but nothing...

Comment: For me, it worked by putting quotes around the password and the username `db.default.password="secret"` and  `db.default.user="play"`

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work for me, which version of play are you using? Mine is the 2.3.8